# Is there an dropbox alternative with public folder using predictable URL

Tags: web-apps, web, web-services, file-sharing

Im looking for a file sharing service where if you share a folder, the files will have a predicable url

For example in dropbox if you make a folder and add two files. If you create a link the url for both of those files are different like:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ijfisoifufu4/file1.txt
https://www.dropbox.com/s/asdasdfff4/file2.txt

I would like to find a service where it would be like:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/asdasdfff4/file1.txt
https://www.dropbox.com/s/asdasdfff4/file2.txt

Is there any?...